# FTP over Secure Gateway on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

We have java application running on bluemix that is supposed to submit some files over FTP to the server located in intranet.

Everything works as expected when executing the application locally, but something goes wrong when the application tries to submit something over the secure gateway.

The Gateway has a destination configured for the port 21. Looking through the logs we can see that the application is able to connect to the server and execute some commands there, but fails when it comes to the file submission (by timeout in case of passive mode and saying that the connection is closed in active)

Passive attempt results:
[image: passive attempt results]

Active attempt results:
[image: active attempt results]

We are able to use the gateway to connect to the external db2 instance successfully.

Is some additional configuration required? Is FTP is possible at all over the Secure Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked on dW Answers at the following URL:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/386433/ftp-over-secure-gateway-on-bluemix.html

As stated in response to that question, SFTP doesn't run over port 21; it runs over port 22.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found at: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/386433/ftp-over-secure-gateway-on-bluemix.html

> "you need to define two secure gateway destinations - one for command
>   port 21 and one for data port, which will depend on your connection
>   mode."